# What is the process involved in acquiring permission to photograph within a mall?

Tags: legal, permission

I have a client who needs to shoot a video of walking into a mall to a kiosk where he will be selling products. The problem is he has gotten kicked out of every mall he has tried to film inside because the malls are "very protective of their property."

Does anyone have any tips for obtaining permission to film a short video inside a mall?

Note: The video is not trying to film people or other stores. Only where the product would be located inside the mall. The video is for demonstration purposes to obtain financing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He needs to talk to the mall management where he has the agreement to setup the kiosk. If he doesn't have an agreement, its unlikely that you will get on.

You should have him offer to shoot before the mall opens, so there won't be privacy issues with customers.

Comment: Often commercial locations are worried about how and in what context they will be represented. They prefer to have control over their public image. Address this question, if you notice hesitation in granting permission to shoot, assure them that the mall will not be identifiable in the resulting video, and offer them to view and demand changes in the video.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Patt,  you have to talk to the mall management, I have one experience that before I acquired the permit, I have to ask the management, explain them that I was doing a school project that time, then they just ask payment for that, while I shoot, a guard has to accompany me. It also depends on the mall policy. Some malls have payment term before you get a permit.   Also, that policy are not only implemented by malls, some park like national parks (depends on a country), implements it.